# How to handle only specific messages using NServiceBus Host

Tags: nservicebus

I have a seperate class library of messages. Each handler implementing IHandleMessages. I also have a seperate class library that uses the NServiceBus.Host to act as a message handling service. I know I can handle the ordering of messages but can I say which message handlers I want the host to handle? At the minute it seems that any reference to IHandleMessage will be handled by the host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom initialize your endpoint and use the With(IEnumerable<Type> typesToScan) overload.  You will need to include the NSB types as well.  I would recommend splitting up the assembly into multiple assemblies and then use the With(IEnumberable assemblies) overload to simplify the process.  You could still deploy all handlers, but just configure endpoints to use a specific set.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have one handler per NServiceBus host? Makes it nice and easy.

Comment: Firstly, because we have than many messages I wouldn't like to bundle it all into one handler. Secondly, the problem would still remain in that the handlers are shared in a single assembly.